# how to integrate ibm iloger flex gantt chart into my flex application

Tags: apache-flex

I have a flex application where i wanted to use gantt chart. So, i have downloaded trail version of ibm iloger in to my system. now my question is how to integrate ibm iloger flex gantt chart in to my flex application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that they have provided you with a SWC file; just add that SWC file to your library path of your project.

Then you should be able to import, and use, their components into your application.

I wrote this blog post about [what to do with a SWC](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/12/18/What-do-you-do-with-a-SWC).